# Collecting books

Tags: style

I am trying to achieve a collection of books by the same author that I can give to my grandchildren. I have collected first editions and mostly first prints. But I am not clear that if I collect the same author from different publishers whether the collection is, strictly speaking, as good as a collection of same author and same publisher

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Writers.SE! We only address questions directly related to writing and publishing; I'm afraid that estimating value of collections is beyond our scope.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about book collecting.